# Is ArrayList of Bundles supported on android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bundle

Can I use the following code, is it correct?

```
ArrayList<Bundle> moviesResult = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
  ...
  Bundle result = new Bundle();
  result.putInt("movieId", movieId);
  result.putString("movieTitle", movieTitle);
  moviesResult.add(result);
}
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Have you not tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You might want to instead make a `Movie` class and then add movie objects directly to an `ArrayList<Movie>`. Using `Bundle` or `Map` you have no guarantee that the few key/value pairs you set actually form a coherent object; in other words, you're losing [encapsulation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct, is there something wrong elsewhere in the app/activity? I would also consider changing your code to look more like how @Matt suggested above.